# get Y-Position out of the Rectangle Hashcode

Tags: c#, wpf, hashcode

everyone,
I have a linechart on a Canvas. I placed a rectangle over each data point and added a MouseEnter event.

```
private void SetDataPointLabels(Point pt)
    {
        
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
        rec.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
        rec.StrokeThickness = 1;
        rec.Width = 5;
        rec.Height = 5;
        rec.MouseEnter += Rec_MouseEnter;
        Canvas.SetTop(rec, pt.Y - 2.5);
        Canvas.SetLeft(rec, pt.X - 2.5);
        ChartCanvas.Children.Add(rec);            
    }
```

I now need the y-position of the rectangle in the event method.

```
private void Rec_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {            
        Console.WriteLine(sender.GetHashCode());
    }
```

In the sender I found the Y position under VisualOffset.

Unfortunately, you can probably only get it via the hash code (sender.GetHashCode()) and I don't know how.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you
Chris

Comment: You can't get information about an object out of its hash code. Hashing is, by definition, a one-way process. The point of a hash code is to quickly determine whether two objects are different or not. Identical objects will always produce the same hash code so, if two objects produce different has codes, you know they are different. If they produce the same has code then they may still not be identical, so you have to do a more thorough comparison. That second comparison will generally be slower, so avoiding it if possible is a good thing.

Comment: You should also set `rec.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;` to receive mouse events not only on the outline, but also on the interior of the shape.

Comment: Thanks Clemens, now I also know why sometimes two events were fired. I probably then touched the outside line twice, for example across the corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sender` argument holds a reference to the Rectangle instance and can therefore be cast to the `Rectangle` type:

```
private void Rec_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{            
    var rec = (Rectangle)sender;
    var y = Canvas.GetTop(rec);
    Debug.WriteLine(y);
}
```

Or just cast to `UIElement` if you want to use the event handler also for other element types:

```
var y = Canvas.GetTop((UIElement)sender);
```